# Want to update a record via a PUT REST API

Tags: jquery-easyui

Another NEWBIE question...  I have a REST API that can update a record using PUT. The server is written in Node.JS + Express + MongoDB.
Clint side is using JQuery and EasyUI.
I am only a beginner and have just learnt that HTML forms cannot do anything but a POST or GET. Therefore how should I develop my UI for an update dialog without using a form ?

Pointers to a sample would be great...

Cormac

Answer (score 1):

In case there is no answer to this.. I discovered I can work around this relatively easily by simply inventing a new pat on the server that is specifically for updating the record I am interested in and using POST for that one also. That means that Create and Update record can both use POST but to different URLs.
Cormac